# PHP - exclude current email from unique validation

Tags: php, validation, crud

I am having problems while updating the data in CRUD because I have defined the validation for email to check all emails from databases.

The code which I have written to validate email is:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO reg (first_name, last_name, email, phone, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

     $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);

     $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM reg WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
        $results = mysqli_query($conn, $user_check_query);
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

            if ($user['email'] === $email) {

             $emailerr="Email Already Exists";



             }

        else{

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $param_fname,$param_lname, $param_email,$param_phone, $param_address);


        $param_fname = $first_name;
        $param_lname = $last_name;
        $param_email = $email;
        $param_phone = $phone;
        $param_address = $address;

        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            header("location:index.php");
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }


    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

I just fetched the data from database on basis of 'ID' but when I click on update it checks the current Email . All I just to check other emails from databases excluding the current email.

Comment: You should use parameterized prepared statements for _both_ your calls, not just for the Update-query.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  can you please write the code for me as I am not expert to it. . . Thanks in advance. . .

Comment: You're already doing it for the second query, or did someone else write your code?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Sorry! It wasn't the second call it was the else statement which is being to be called if email doesn't exist in the database . I edited the code again. Check the code again .Well I am writing by myself but I am just a beginner at programming.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this approach will work , if you just want to check if email is there or not you can use count.
if count > 0 then email is already there , there is no need of

```
if ($user['email'] === $email) {

         $emailerr="Email Already Exists";
}
```

you have already checked email in SQL query , no need to check again.
Hope this helps